# CSV data in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am having trouble using the Import and Vectorize data step to import a CSV into Azure Search AI.

I need to get a CSV of 100.000+ records working but cant seem to get it up and running. I’ve tried a few thing with the delimiter, tweaking the skillset on what level it needs to retrieve content (document/ instead of document/pages/) and more of that good stuff.

What I am trying to archieve is:
The csv contains data of items, where they are used, who used them, when did they got used etc.
What i am trying to archieve is to ask, Who used item X on location Y

But whatever i am trying, i keep getting error that:

- Unable to retrieve content;
- Unable to retrieve vectors.

I tried to convert the csv to JSON, but then i get limited to 20 references.

Is it possible for Azure search to actually vectorize CSV data this large?

I tried to upload a CSV, but its not able to connect the data with eachother.
I tried to convert CSV into JSON, JSON array and JSON Multilines. But this gave a limit on max 20 references (so it doesnt look further then this).

Comment: So assuming you are using the delimitedText parsingMode, you would need to pass in the correct column name from your CSV (and make sure you are specifying it via either the firstLineContainsHeaders or delimitedTextHeaders parameters) as "/documnet/columnName". I'd be curious to know what the exact error message you are receiving if you are already doing that so that I can help debug more.

Comment: Hello Carey and thanks for assisting again. I made a new simple svc with 4 columns and 100 rows. I used delimitedText on ';' with firstlinecontainsheaders. 
I receive 2 errors per row:
1.
Could not execute skill because one or more skill input was invalid. ==> Missing or empty value '/document/content'.

2.
Could not generate projection from input '/document/pages/*'. ==> Cannot iterate over non-array '/document/pages'


It seems now that it doesnt understand its a CSV and makes big lines out of it (when i look at the index, i see 2 documents.

Comment: You need to update the "/document/content" in your skillset to be the name of the column that you want to be vectorized. So "/document/columnName". Should be in the input to your SplitSkill.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the skillset is not correctly configured to process the CSV data.
To fix this, there are few things you can check and modify.

1. **Specify the correct parsing mode**
   Below is sample payload for reference:

```py
indexer_payload = {
   "name": indexer_name,
   "dataSourceName": datasource_name,
   "targetIndexName": index_name,
   "skillsetName": skillset_name,
   "schedule" : { "interval" : "PT2H"},
   "fieldMappings": [
       {
         "sourceFieldName" : "uid",
         "targetFieldName" : "id"
       },      
   ],
   "outputFieldMappings":
   [
       {
           "sourceFieldName": "/document/pages/*",
           "targetFieldName": "chunks"
       }
   ],
   "parameters" : { 
       "configuration" : { 
           "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
           "parsingMode" : "delimitedText", 
           "firstLineContainsHeaders" : True,
           "delimitedTextDelimiter": ","
       } 
   }
}
```

2. **Update the skillset input**:In your skillset definition, update the input field for the SplitSkill to use the correct column name from your CSV file. Replace `/document/content` with `/document/columnName`, where `columnName` is the name of the column you want to vectorize.

```py
"skills": [
 {
   "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
   "textSplitMode": "pages",
   "maximumPageLength": 4000,
   "inputs": [
     {
       "name": "text",
       "source": "/document/columnName"
     }
   ],
   "outputs": [
     {
       "name": "textItems",
       "targetName": "pages"
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

For detailed example, you can check this sample [notebook](https://github.com/pablomarin/GPT-Azure-Search-Engine/blob/main/02-LoadCSVOneToMany-ACogSearch.ipynb) which demonstrate indexing of large csv file and creating vectors.